# How to convert text file to spark dataframe using spark scala UDF functions

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a input data like below:

```
id###name##salary#dept
1##John#10000########IT
2####Mindhack Diva#20000########IT
3####Michel#30000########IT
4###Ryan#40000########IT
5####Sahoo#10000########IT
```

[image]

How to convert text file to dataframe using spark scala?

I need output like the below dataframe, can anyone pls help me on this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PySpark**

I know how to get the result by pyspark and this might help you or not.

```
import re

rdd = sc.textFile('test.txt').map(lambda r: re.split('[#]+', r))
cols = rdd.first()

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.filter(lambda r: r != cols)).toDF(*cols)
df.show(truncate=False)

+---+-------------+------+----+
|id |name         |salary|dept|
+---+-------------+------+----+
|1  |John         |10000 |IT  |
|2  |Mindhack Diva|20000 |IT  |
|3  |Michel       |30000 |IT  |
|4  |Ryan         |40000 |IT  |
|5  |Sahoo        |10000 |IT  |
+---+-------------+------+----+
```